# Find the count of a variable grouped by another variable

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that has GVKEY, GICS and 10 years of fundamental data for each firm from COMPUSTAT. I want to find the number of firms for each GICS classification in Stata. Note that I have only those firms that have all 10 years of data, so the firm number is constant across years.

Answer (score 0):

You could go

```
tab GICS
```

and divide by 10 or go

```
egen tag = tag(GVKEY)
tab GICS if tag
```

See also `distinct` from the *Stata Journal* and the tips and tricks in [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0042).